# How to implement code-signing with FreeRTOS OTA and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, esp32, code-signing, aws-iot, freertos

I'm working on an ESP32 device that has been configured to receive OTA updates via AWS and FreeRTOS.  As part of the initial configuration for these devices, they were flashed with a hard-coded certificate that was used for code-signing.  This is distinct from the certificates the device uses to connect to MQTT to receive the update.

This worked fine until recently, when the original certificate expired and thus prevented me from delivering signed images to the devices as they now don't match the certificate flashed on the device.

Since I plan on having many of these devices deployed, what is the correct way to set-up these certificates such that when one expires or is revoked, I can still verify a new one without re-flashing each device?

I have tried using AWS Private Root CA and generating a certificate from that, but was unable to give it the right extensions and use it with a signing profile and AWS IoT.  I haven't been able to find clear information about the right way to implement code-signing with AWS and FreeRTOS.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your device's certificate, it is good to have the capability to renew this signing certificate.
Not only because they expire, but also in case it is compromised. 
You could use aws iot jobs to trigger a signing certificate update before the cert expires.

Not sure how your fleet operates but there might a chance that you want to trigger an update while not all devices have been updating their signing certificate. In this case, you could create two OTAs, one for old certificate and one for the new one.